# How to skip packageExtensions in Yarn 2+ (Berry)

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

Yarn 2+ (Berry) was implemented packages dependencies check, but I don't want to [fix dependencies with packageExtensions](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#fix-dependencies-with-packageextensions). Is it possible to disable dependencies check feature?

Comment: `yarn config unset packageExtensions`?

Comment: @double-beep is `unset` disable packages dependencies check or just remove `packageExtensions` section from config?